# return a databag given a tuple in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to write an UDF which takes a tuple as an input and return a databag as an output. I am very new to PIG. Please help. The example I have is the UPPER.java class example.

example of what the UDF should do 
the input is say <8,9,1,8,9> the output should be <{8,2} {9,2} {1,1}> 8 appears 2 times, 9 does too and 1 appears once.

Comment: Be more specific. What do you want your UDF to *do* with the tuple? How is the `DataBag` related to it?

Comment: the input is say <8,9,1,8,9> the output should be <{8,2} {9,2} {1,1}> 8 appears 2 times, 9 does too and 1 appears once. So it is like a frequency count. I need to use a UDF to do this

Comment: That's important information to put into the question. Try writing your code and then we can take a look at where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

---

**Step 1**: Load input file

```
input_data= load '/idn/home/ksing143/tuple_related_data/tuple_frequency.txt' USING PigStorage() AS ip_tuple:tuple(a:int, b:int, c:int, d:int, e:int);
```

Result:

```
((8,9,1,8,9))
```

---

**Step 2**: flatten the input tuple

```
ip_flattened = foreach input_data generate FLATTEN($0);
```

---

**Step 3**: Convert to bag

```
ip_tobag = foreach ip_flattened generate TOBAG(ip_tuple::a,ip_tuple::b,ip_tuple::c,ip_tuple::d,ip_tuple::e);
```

Result:

```
({(8),(9),(1),(8),(9)})
```

---

**Step 4**: Flatten the bag

```
ip_tobag_flattened = foreach ip_tobag generate FLATTEN($0);
```

Result:

```
(8)
(9)
(1)
(8)
(9)
```

---

**Step 5**: Perform Grouping and then count

```
ip_grouped = group ip_tobag_flattened BY $0;
ip_out = foreach ip_grouped generate group, COUNT($1);
```

Result:

```
(1,1)
(8,2)
(9,2)
```

---

**Step 6**: Convert output TOBAG as we want output in the form of bag.

```
ip_output_bag = foreach ip_out generate TOBAG($0,$1);
```

Result:

```
({(1),(1)})
({(8),(2)})
({(9),(2)})
```